# Is Oracle REST Data Services compatible for .NET CORE?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, oracle-rest-data-services

I am exploring the option to utilize Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) for a .NET Core web application. Does anyone has similar experiences or suggestions whether this is accomplishable? From the Oracle documentation, it seems like it's mostly for java application, any suggestions would be helpful, and I appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is Oracle REST Data Services compatible for .NET CORE?

No, `Oracle REST Data Services` is a Java EE-based alternative for Oracle HTTP Server and mod_plsql. The Java EE implementation offers increased functionality including a command line based configuration, enhanced security, file caching, and RESTful web services. Oracle REST Data Services also provides increased flexibility by supporting deployments using Oracle WebLogic Server, GlassFish Server, Apache Tomcat, and a standalone mode.

The Oracle Application Express architecture requires some form of web server to proxy requests between a web browser and the Oracle Application Express engine. **Oracle REST Data Services** satisfies this need but its use goes beyond that of Oracle Application Express configurations. Oracle REST Data Services simplifies the deployment process because there is no Oracle home required, as connectivity is provided using an embedded `JDBC` driver.

Reference: [REST Data Services Installation and Configuration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37099_01/doc.20/e25066/install.htm#AELIG7017)

---

But you could create .NET Core web application that retrieves data from the Oracle database with Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) Core.

`ODP.NET Core` is an `ADO.NET` driver that provides fast data access from Microsoft .NET Core clients to Oracle databases. It runs on both Windows and Linux. ODP.NET consists of a single 100% managed code dynamic-link library, `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`, available via `NuGet` deployment.

You could check the details from this article [Getting Started with ODP.NET Core](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/ODPNET_Core_get_started/index.html)